# Como manter carregado item do listview

Tags: android, listview

Tenho este listview

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
xmlns:ads = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#ffffff"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/praias"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

layoutlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Bertioga"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:id="@+id/nomePraia"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fotoPraia"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nomePraia"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bt" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Coemçar a descrição ...."
    android:id="@+id/descricao"
    android:maxLength="400"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btVerMais"
        android:id="@+id/btVerMais"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="@color/wallet_link_text_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btFavorito"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_popup_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**adapter.java**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, null);
    final ListenerItem categoria = itens.get(position);
    ImageView foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fotoPraia);
    int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(categoria.nome_foto, "drawable", packageName);
    LoadBitmapImage bitmapTask = new LoadBitmapImage(foto,width,context);
    bitmapTask.execute(drawableId);
    TextView nomePraia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomePraia);

    final ImageButton btFavorito = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btFavorito);
    TextView descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
    final Button bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt);
    Button btVerMais = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btVerMais);
    String desc="";
    if(categoria.descricao.length()<397){
        btVerMais.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        desc=categoria.descricao;
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<397;i++){
            desc=desc+categoria.descricao.charAt(i);
        }
        desc=desc+"...";
    }
    nomePraia.setText(categoria.nome);
    String nome_foto = categoria.nome_foto;


    descricao.setText(desc);

    if (categoria.favorito) {
        btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);
    } else {
        btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);
    }
    btVerMais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenerItem listenerItem = new ListenerItem();

            listenerItem = itens.get(position);
            open(listenerItem);
        }
    });
    btFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenerItem listenerItem = new ListenerItem();

            listenerItem = itens.get(position);

            if (listenerItem.favorito) {
                listenerItem.favorito = false;
                btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);
                chamaToast(false);
            } else {
                listenerItem.favorito = true;
                btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);
                chamaToast(true);
            }

            try {
                daoItem.createOrUpdate(listenerItem);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    activity.registerForContextMenu(bt);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bt.setId(position);
            activity.openContextMenu(bt);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Neste meu `ListView` carrega um item ai quando vai descendo o `ScrollView` do `ListView`vai carregando os outro itens um por vez eu queria manter estes itens carregados , depois que carregar uma vez não precisar carregar de novo

**Novo Adapter**

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fotoPraia);
        holder.btFavorito = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btFavorito);
        holder.nomePraia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomePraia);
        holder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        holder.bt = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.bt);
        holder.btVerMais = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btVerMais);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    final ListenerItem categoria = itens.get(position);
    int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(categoria.nome_foto, "drawable", packageName);

    LoadBitmapImage bitmapTask = new LoadBitmapImage(holder.foto,width,context);
    bitmapTask.execute(drawableId);

    String desc="";
    if(categoria.descricao.length()<397){
        holder.btVerMais.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        desc=categoria.descricao;
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<397;i++){
            desc=desc+categoria.descricao.charAt(i);
        }
        desc=desc+"...";
    }
    holder.nomePraia.setText(categoria.nome);
    holder.descricao.setText(desc);

    if (categoria.favorito) {
        holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);
    } else {
        holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);
    }
    holder.btVerMais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenerItem listenerItem = new ListenerItem();

            listenerItem = itens.get(position);
            open(listenerItem);
        }
    });
    holder.btFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenerItem listenerItem = new ListenerItem();

            listenerItem = itens.get(position);

            if (listenerItem.favorito) {
                listenerItem.favorito = false;
                holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);

            } else {
                listenerItem.favorito = true;
                holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);

            }

            try {
                daoItem.createOrUpdate(listenerItem);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    activity.registerForContextMenu(holder.bt);

    holder.bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.bt.setId(position);
            activity.openContextMenu(holder.bt);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Classe ViewHolder

```
private class ViewHolder {
public ImageView foto;
public TextView nomePraia;
public ImageButton btFavorito;
public TextView descricao;
public ImageButton bt;
public Button btVerMais;
```

}

**Modo Que carrego as imagens**
Classe que estou usando pra carregar
**LoadBitmapImage**

```
public class LoadBitmapImage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private final int width;
private Context context;

public LoadBitmapImage(ImageView imageView,int width,Context context) {
    this.width = width;
    this.context = context;
    // Use a WeakReference para ter certeza que sua ImageView sera reciclada
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Carregando a imagem em background
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... drawableId) {
    // Aqui voce utiliza seus proprios metodos para carregar e configurar sua Bitmap
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId[0]);
    bm = bm.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, width, true);
    return bm;
}

// Quando completo, coloque o Bitmap em sua ImageView
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Estás a falar das imagens?

Comment: ou as imagens ou tudo , só para não precisar carregar de novo

Comment: De onde vêm as imagens?

Comment: as imagens ja estão no drawable mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma maneira melhor de implementar o método `getView`, utilizando o conceito de ViewHolders, onde as suas Views estão em uma outra classe (Holder). Por exemplo:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
        holder.imageView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.seuImageView);
        holder.textView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.seuTextView);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    Object item = getItem(position);

    return v;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView1;
    TextView textView1;
}
```

O ListView recicla os itens da lista para não ficar criando outra vez, basicamente ele mantem na memória apenas os que estão na tela e o próximo item a ser mostrado. Fazendo seu getView assim, utilizando um holder para manipular suas Views você evita que o ListView reutilize suas Views já criadas, modificando seus dados.

Comment: Coloquei o holder no meu adapter mais está gerando outro problema alem do que eu tava já , tem hora que está mostrando o item repetido , e tem hora que carrega o item de modo errado , vou colocar o novo adapter la

Comment: A "mágica" acontece na linha do if (convertView == null) {

Comment: oque está errado no meu?

Comment: Na primeira linha do seu getView o seu "View view" precisa receber o convertView: View view = convertView

Comment: o if vai trocar para `if ( view ==null) `ou continua o `if (convertView == null)`

Comment: Tanto faz nesta etapa os 2 são iguais

Comment: rafael , se eu faço o carregamento da minha imagem dentro desse getview trava o aplicativo ate a imagem ser carregada , ai eu coloquei uma clase pra carregar em background mais ai ta ficando a imagem anterior ate a imagem do item atual carregar, você sabe algum jeito de carregar essa imagem mais eficiente?

Comment: Na minha experiência com carregamento de imagens o melhor framework que usei foi o Volley do Google, ele tem um ImageView (NetworkImageView) que faz todo o trabalho pra você. Também há o Square Picasso que é muito bom, tão fácil quanto. Todo carregamento de imagem deve ser feito numa task separada e estes 2 fazem isso muito bem, inclusive com a opção de mostrar uma imagem qualquer enquanto a sua é carregada.

Comment: ata, vou procurar saber mais disso obrigado